# Link to the full list of badges from the truncated list

Tags: feature-request, bug, badges, profile-page, user-interface

I wanted to see which badges a user had, so I opened the “Profile” tab of their profile. Under their avatar and reputation, a box shows 4 bronze badges

[image: badge display under the avatar and reputation]

Below, in the “Badges” area, I see three of those badges:

[image: badges area]

Ok, so the box has a size limit and there's no room for the 4th badge. I'll have to follow the link to the complete list then.

Er, no, there's no link. The “Badges” area doesn't contain a link to the full list. Neither does the box under the avatar.

Contrast with other areas such as “Top Tags” and “Top Posts”, which do link to the full list when they don't show everything.

When you show a truncated list, please link to the full list.

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean this link?

> [image: all badges]

But sometimes [there is no link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/210600/takkat):

> [image: no link]

Probably the edge limit for detecting need of link is wrong.